# XAML How to own StaticResource in derived UserControl class

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, styles

I have the following problem. I have a class which derives from UserControl, here is the code:

```
public partial class MyUC : UserControl
{
[...]
    public bool IsFlying { get { return true; } }
[...]
}
```

I want to use a style, which is created for the class MyUC, below is the style code. It is located in App.Xaml :

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="mystyle" TargetType="dc:MyUC ">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFlying" Value="true">
                <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

As you can see I want to use a property which I declared in MyUC.
The problem is that when I am trying to add a style to my control, an error occurres.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyUC"
         [...]
         Style="{StaticResource mystyle}"> 
<UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

The error is: **'MyUC' TargetType does not match type of element 'UserControl'.**

As far as I understand, the compiler do not recognize class MyUC to be derived from UserControl. How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error might be at `design` time only, it should work fine at `runtime`. Run your app and see if it works for you.

Moreover your trigger won't work for `normal CLR property`, you need to make it a `Dependency Property` -

```
    public bool IsFlying
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFlyingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsFlyingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFlyingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsFlying", typeof(bool), 
           typeof(SampleUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
```

Also, you can remove the `x:Key="mystyle"` from your style declaration. It will automatically gets applied to your UserControl.

That way you won't have to explicitly set style on your UserControl. This line won't be required then - `Style="{StaticResource mystyle}"`

Comment: Than you very much for your nice reply. It hit the spot. Registering dependency property fixed my code.